# Unable to SSH over proxycommand over multiple servers

Tags: ssh, proxy, virtual-machines

I have a jump server (server1) which on a private network where I want to use as a jump server to access other network resource such as other servers. Server1 holds required ssh key files for other servers on the private network.

So when I use SSH --> Server 1 then SSH from Server 1 --> Server 2 manually using, it works as expected.
However, when I try and chain it over SSH using ProxyCommand, I get an error:

```
λ ssh -t  -i ~/.ssh/key1.pem -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/key2.pem azureuser@10.0.2.4" azureuser@13.86.0.0

ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.4 port 22: Connection timed out
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have also tried the ssh -J option to do a similar thing but doesn't feel like it's possible to pass a remote identity file using that.

Comment: A timeout is not the same as an authentication issue. What do you get if you run this command with `-v`?